# UnitTest is expected ModelState to be invalid but it isn't

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, nunit

I have a .NetCore MVC project and I'm trying to unit test my controller.

ViewModel **(Note the `[Required]` attribute)**:

```
public class Bank : BaseObject
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Bank")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name")] Bank bank)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _bankService.Insert(bank);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(bank);
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[Test]
public async Task When_PostingCreateBankThatIsInvalid_ThenBankIsReturned()
{
    var bank = new Bank
    {
        //nothing set = invalid state - this is what we want
    };
    var controller = new BanksController(null);
    var response = await controller.Create(bank);
}
```

I was expected the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` to return false as `Name` is required - then I was going to perform my `Asserts` based on that. But the result is true and so we try to insert a bank.

What am I doing wrong here? I've Googled but I can only find answers that don't relate to unit tests. I thought the `ModelState` upheld the `[Required]` attribute?

If I test using the UI I am unable to create a bank without a name - it never even reaches the controller (as expected).

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> Model validation occurs prior to each controller action being invoked

so I believe the problem lies with how I'm creating the `BanksController`. Am I approaching this test in the wrong manner? I wonder if I should just be setting the `ModelState` to invalid in the test...?

Comment: From the docs quote, I expect you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are metadata that is only recognized by the framework at run time and not during a unit test as they are actually read by the model binder that when the application is running.

For the state to change you will either have to run an integration test where the necessary parts of the framework are available to update the model state,

or update the model state manually since model binding isn't running (though an integration test would be used to exercise model binding) in the controller so that the test behaves as expected when being exercised.

```
[Test]
public async Task When_PostingCreateBankThatIsInvalid_ThenBankIsReturned() {
    //Arrange
    var bank = new Bank
    {
        //nothing set = invalid state - this is what we want
    };
    var controller = new BanksController(null);
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name","Name required");

    //Act
    var response = await controller.Create(bank);

    //Assert
    response.Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.BeOfType<ViewResult>();

    var viewResult = response as ViewResult;
    viewResult.Model.Should().Be(model);
}
```

> Don't try to test model validation or model binding in your unit tests - just test your action method's behavior when confronted with a particular ModelState value.

Reference [Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)